# Incorrect full width of the item in Swiper

Tags: swiper.js

I`m using Swiper with such params:

```
var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
                    slidesPerView: 6,
                    spaceBetween: 15,

                    nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
                    prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev'
});
```

Usual the width of items is ok (see image 1)
[image]
But sometimes the page is loaded with an item which width is 100% of the parent container width. (see image 2)[image]

How can i fix it?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? We are seeing the same thing using Swiper with Ember...